# Getting server time and using it in python

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

I have a unique situation where I am in need of pulling the current time from an SQL server and using that value in my python program as a string. I don't know how to pull it down to print or assign to a variable.

Example:

do stuff...
var = mySQL server datetime <---- How do i do that part ??
print var;
do more stuff...

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a library like [_mysql](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) to connect to the server then something like this should work.

```
import _mysql

db = _mysql.connect(host="localhost",user="user", passwd="pass", db="db")
db.execute('select now()')
r = db.store_result()

time_var = r[0][0]

print time_var
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases your safest bet is to work with GMT and calculate the offset wherever you need it. If you need to get the date from MySQL however it should look similar to this:

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="")

c = db.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT NOW()")
current_time = c.fetchone()
```

the `current_time` will be a datetime.datetime object and you can treat it any way you like from there

Comment: I believe fetchone will return a single element tuple, you'll have to unpack it to have the value assigned properly. `current_time, = c.fetchone()` should work.